# How to assign new different values to numpy array at the same dimension using iteration function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iteration

I have the following multidimensional numpy array:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape(2,2,2,2)
```

I want to assign new different values of the array for each element of certain dimension e.g. 4th dimension
I used the following code:

```
    for i in range(a.shape[3]):
          if i == 0:
               for t in np.nditer(a[:,:,:,i], op_flags = ['readwrite']):
                    t[...] = t*2
          if i == 1:
               for t in np.nditer(a[:,:,:,i], op_flags = ['readwrite']):
                    t[...] = t*3

print(a)
print(a.shape)
```

the output is shown as

```
[[[[ 0  1]
   [ 4  3]]

   [[ 8  5]
   [12  7]]]


 [[[16  9]
   [20 11]]

  [[24 13]
   [28 15]]]]
[[[[ 0  3]
   [ 4  9]]

  [[ 8 15]
   [12 21]]]


 [[[16 27]
   [20 33]]

  [[24 39]
   [28 45]]]]
(2, 2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 2, 2)
```

What I understand that it iterates over the array and at the first `i` it assigns new values then at the next `i` it assigns new values and creates new array with both new values besides the first array of the first `i` that's why I got two arrays in one variable. I only concern about the last array where all values have been assigned the new values. How could I extract the last array only. Or there is another code which is simpler and time saving for this task?

Comment: don't use `nditer`.  It doesn't speed up anything and only adds complications if you don't understand it well.

Comment: Then, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
>>> a[:,:,:,0] = a[:,:,:,0]*2
>>> a[:,:,:,1] = a[:,:,:,1]*3
>>> a
array([[[[ 0,  3],
         [ 4,  9]],

        [[ 8, 15],
         [12, 21]]],


       [[[16, 27],
         [20, 33]],

        [[24, 39],
         [28, 45]]]])
```

Or even this:

```
>>> a[:,:,:,0] *= 2
>>> a[:,:,:,1] *= 3
```

Comment: That sounds good and simple. But in case of a big array with e.g. 400 elements in that dimension and use in the replacement formula corresponding values from another array 

example a and b are arrays: 

    a.shape 
    (2,2,2,400)

    b.shape
    (400)

    for i in range(temp.shape[3]): 
        a[:,:,:,i] = a[:,:,:,i] * b[corresponding i]

I think it does not make sense to write line for each element

Comment: I used zip to iterate over two arrays and use your formulation and it is working now. Thanks alot